# Mimic raster output from ArcGIS GWR (raster gradient through NA spaces) in R

Tags: r, stars

I'm trying to mimic the raster style output you get from ArcGIS Geographically Weighted Regression, where instead of simply plotting the coefficient/value in the raster cell that aligns with the coordinate point assigned the value leaving all in-between cells NA, it (at least appears to) fill them by a gradient. See ArcGIS screenshot for what I am aiming for.

[image: ArcGIS Style Output]

[image: R STARS output]

[image: R STARS outuput using NA omit]

Here's an repex

```
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)
library(stars)

df <- quakes %>%
  select(depth, long, lat) %>%
  st_as_sf(coords = c("long", "lat"),
           crs = 4326)

df_rast <- st_rasterize(df)

ggplot() +
  geom_stars(data = df_rast)

ggplot() +
  geom_stars(data = df_rast,
             na.action = na.omit)
```

Comment: For those of us without an ESRI license, can you link to the documentation for the GWR functionality? I'd assume its maybe doing an inverse distance weighting smoothing over the points, but maybe its evaluating something else over a grid...

Comment: For the ESRI documentation, pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/… doesn't mention anything about how the raster is created, only that it is an optional output you can look at. Is there somewhere else I should be looking?